# Why is my mesh highlighting the geometry?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Firstly, I apologize if this has been asked. I tried to search but I wasn’t even sure what terminology to use to describe what’s happening to my models. But I’ve modeled a drum clip for an assault rifle but some of the mesh is highlighting each individual polygon, here’s what I mean:

[image]

See how it kind of looks like a circular pattern and then again on the rounded sides you can see the individual geometry? What’s causing that and how can I remedy it? Thank you in advance for your help.

Here's what it looks like in edit mode:

[image]

Comment: this happens as a shading artifact when your mesh doesn't have enough geometry to be smoothed out nicely. another solution is to add a subdivision surface modifier.

Comment: @person132 That makes sense, I was kinda suspecting it might be something like that. This is good to know for my future models, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling Auto Smooth.

Select the object to be smoothed in the 3D View then access Object Data properties. Scroll down to/find the Normals options (click the ► arrow to expand) and click the checkbox marked Auto Smooth

Hope that helps.

Comment: That did it, thank you so much!